# mmenu position & direction attributes to slide in from right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mmenu

I read another person's question asking how to make mmenu slide in from the right side of the screen instead of the left. They responded saying that they got it to work by doing the following, but it does not work in my instance - it still moves in from the left side of the screen, not the right like I want.

The mmenu related files are the latest from http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/, so I do not believe it's a version issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>mmenu test</title>
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" href="jquery.mmenu.all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mmenu.min.all.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var API = $("#menu").mmenu({
            dragOpen: true,
            position:'right',
            direction:'right'
        }).data( "mmenu" );
        $("#menu-button").click(function() {
            API.open();
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
This is some body content
</div>
<button id="menu-button">open/close</button>

<nav id="menu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about">About us</a>
</ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Define "it doesn't work".

Comment: It still moves in from left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this page of the plugin documentation](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/extensions/positioning.html), you need to include the "positioning" extension. I guess it is already included in your case, because you call the `all.js` and `all.css` files.

Then, use the following code :

```
$("#menu").mmenu({
   offCanvas: {
      position: "right"
   }
});
```

Comment: Just managed to find this in their documentation via a Google search when you posted. This is the correct answer. The method of just setting those attributes does not work. I'll post a link to the previous question so it can be correct for the current version. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
 <script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="path/to/jquery.mmenu.js"></script>
 <link href="path/to/jquery.mmenu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="path/to/jquery.mmenu.positioning.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#my-menu").mmenu({
         extensions: ["position-right"]
      });
   });
</script>
```